# Why doesn't Google Patents how expiration dates anymore?

Tags: expiration, google-patents

Does anyone know why Google patents no longer shows the anticipated expiration date for issued patents?

As seen in red in the below image, I relied on Google Patents for a quick-and-dirty idea of a Patent's expiration date. The advantage of that over "20 years from earliest non-provisional filing" was that Google Patents took patent term adjustments (though not terminal disclaimers) into account.
[image]

As seen in a screenshot taken today, I no longer see the anticipated expiration when I view patents on Google Patents. Anyone know why not?

This change seems to be sitewide, not limited to just this patent.

[image]

Comment: It's an interesting observation. I'm afraid no one outside of Google will be able to answer. It may be that Google found their estimates to be too likely wrong. See this question for something relevant. https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/23109/calculating-a-patent-expiration-date-from-pairs-and-patent-term-calculator?rq=1